# Bad substitution inside xargs subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I'm using this command to process PNG files:

```
find . -iname "*png" -print0 | xargs -r0 --max-procs=4 -n1 sh -c 'pngnq -s1 $1 && advpng -z -4 -q ${$1%.*}-nq8.png' -
```

It seems to actually work fine, but also outputs this for each file that it processes:

```
-: 1: -: Bad substitution
```

I assume that I'm doing something wrong here `${$1%.*}` - but I'm really not sure. The trailing dash is there on purpose, as per the docs [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-the-shell-from-xargs.html#Invoking-the-shell-from-xargs) - and I can't just pipe the whole thing because `advpng` can't process things from stdin/out, sadly - so I have to use filenames.

Anyone know how to fix this so it doesn't have this error?

Comment: I was using a trailing dash, but the docs I linked use a trailing string value - it doesn't really matter. If you don't pass an initial value into the shell, you get a different error and nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An obvious problem is the missing quoting:

```
... sh -c 'pngnq -s1 "$1" && advpng -z -4 -q "${1%.*}"-nq8.png' -
```

You are right about your assumption that `${$1%.*}` is the real problem. You must not repeat the `$` in the brackets.

The docs say nothing about a trailing dash, do they? Just about a name.

Comment: I think you should first state the real problem and the solution, and after that as an additional tip mention the potential quoting issue in case the filenames have spaces or other characters that need quoting.

Comment: I was using a trailing dash, but the docs I linked use a trailing string value - it doesn't really matter. If you don't pass an initial value into the shell, you get a different error and nothing works. Your solution works, though - wrong quoting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
find . -iname "*png" -print0 | parallel -0 pngnq -s1 {} '&&' advpng -z -4 -q {.}-nq8.png
```

You can find more about GNU Parallel at: http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/

You can install GNU Parallel in just 10 seconds with:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Watch the intro video on http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1